# I am getting on so many error on my test class

Tags: unit-test

I am getting an error `Illegal assignment from String to Date` and when I  run the test class another error

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

```
Account acc = [Select Id from Account limit 1];
Contact con = [Select Id from Contact limit 1];


"Illegal assignment from String to Date", I tried everything but still getting error
Date_referred_to_Services__c = '28-02-2020' - Date format on the system is DD-MM-YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY

@isTest static void MyTestClass() {
       Test.startTest();   

        User U1 = [SELECT ID from User Where FederationIdentifier = 'Icandothis' LIMIT 1];
        system.debug ('User =' +' '+U1);

        System.runas(U1) {

        Account acc = [Select Id from Account limit 1];
        Contact con = [Select Id from Contact limit 1];
        Case cs = new Case (RecordTypeId = Constants.RECORDTYPEID_CLAIM,  Subject = 'TestCase', 
                            Status = 'Claim', Origin = 'Phone', Claim_Outcome__c = 'Successfully Closed', 
                            Claim_Outcome_Reason__c = 'lodgement', Payment_Amount__c = 2000, 
                            Sum_Insured__c = 20000, Premium_Refund_Value__c = 34000, 
                            All_relevant_information_in_Rooms__c ='Yes', 
                            Date_referred_to_Services__c = '28-02-2020', ContactId = con.Id, 
                            AccountId = acc.Id
                            );       

        insert cs; 

       Test.stopTest();

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Always try to avoid SOQL for test data  because in that case your test class depend on  your sandbox data. You May get some issue will deployment.**

Please refer to [Code Coverage Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_best_pract.htm)

Do not query Account/contacts like below

```
Account acc = [Select Id from Account limit 1];
```

instead create a date in test class like

```
Account acc = new Account(name = 'testacc');
insert acc;
```

Now, instead of `Date_referred_to_Services__c = '28-02-2020',`
You can do this using Apex's Date class:

```
Date_referred_to_Services__c = Date.newInstance(2018, 12, 9);
```

For more information on dates, check out the documentation: [Date Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

If you want to query data from organization instead of creating in test class, annotate your test class or test method with `IsTest(SeeAllData=true)` to open up data access to records in your organization. 
Refer [this document for more information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm)

Comment: Hi Samir, can you please clarify this I am not getting what you mean here. I only have date on the case not on the account  ..."Also, it seems that you are querying the account in test class. This is not recommended. Create a test date in your test class and assign the same account to accountId"

Comment: I have updated the answer with more information

Comment: IsTest(SeeAllData=true)  - we cannot do this.

Comment: with seeAllData, you can query the database. You do not create the data. But this can cause issue in production as the data with matching criteria might not be available in database. But when you create a data in test class, there is always a guarantee that the matching data will always be there for your test class. This is also one of the best practice for writing test class

Comment: I am having issue with Federation ID I cannot create a new user with it since it is unique. It is throwing an error. When I changed the actual Federation ID it run but it did not cover the lines.

Comment: Annotate your class or method with `seealldata = true` and just write a soql for user. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Now I am getting this System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id        AF; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Comment: Error is in test class or main class?

Comment: @Samir Users are treated as metadata and are visible in unit tests. You do not need and should not use `SeeAllData=true` to access Users.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed for correction